# Adjust position of pagination link

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="pager"><a href="asd" title="go to page 1" class="disabled">1</a>
<a href="asd" title="go to page 2">2</a>
<a href="asd" title="go to page 3">3</a><span class="elip">...</span>
<a href="asd" title="go to page 4">4</a></div>
```

And CSS:

```
.elip
{
padding-top:3px;
letter-spacing:2px;
margin-left:5px;
}

#pager a{    
BORDER-BOTTOM: #E6E6E6 1px solid; 
BORDER-TOP: #E6E6E6 1px solid;
BORDER-RIGHT: #E6E6E6 1px solid; 
BORDER-LEFT: #E6E6E6 1px solid;
color: #585858;
padding: 7px;
padding-top:30px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #808080;
}
```

No matter what I do, I cannot get the '...' to be aligned down the bottom at the bottom. When testing in JSFiddle, all works, but not outside it as the shot below (red X is what it is, green tick is what I would like):
[image]

Padding, text size, alignment, line height, nothing seems to work.

Comment: i see the same problem in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ptriek/LfUDB/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/pELcX/):

```
.elip {
    padding-top:3px;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    margin-left:5px;
    position:relative;
    bottom:-10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use relative positioning, I also cleaned up your css a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/ptriek/LfUDB/2/

```
.elip {
padding-top:3px;
letter-spacing:2px;
margin-left:5px;
}

#pager a {    
border: #E6E6E6 1px solid; 
color: #808080;
padding:30px 7px 7px 7px;
text-decoration: none;
}

#pager span {
    top: 9px;
    position:relative;
}
```